# Undefined Meteor.user() after refresh Angular2 Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm quite new to Angular2 and Meteor.
I want to do a pretty simple thing : Get the current user information from Meteor with Meteor.user().
The thing is, whenever I refresh the page, the profile value of Meteor.user() becomes "undefined".

I did some search, apparently Meteor.user() is too long to be execute.
Apparently, you can use Tracker.autorun() to wait for Meteor.user() to get initialized.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
Tracker.autorun(function () {
        Meteor.subscribe("userLoggedIn");
        console.log(Meteor.user());
        if(Meteor.user() !== undefined) {
           //Do something
           this.myFunction();
        }
     });
```

The thing is that "myFunction" is "undefined" since it's not defined in the Tracker (I think at least).

Do you have any idea how can I call my function ?
Is this ok to execute that much of code in the tracker ?
Is it possible to wait for the initialization of Meteor.user() outside of the Tracker ?

(Yeah, i've got a lot of question :p )

Thank you by advance ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are relying on `this`, why not using an arrow function to keep the context?

```
Tracker.autorun(() => { this.myFunction(); });
```

You could also set a scoped variable, old school way:

```
var self = this;

Tracker.autorun(function () { /* bla bla */ self.myFunction(); });
```

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you ! Except for one wierd point. If I refresh my page, the value send from my component isn't showing until I click on a composent of my view (like a textearea).

Do you know what could cause that ? Knowing that my Tracker function is in "ngOnInit".

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Alright I found my answer ! I needed to add zone.run() !
Thanks you for your help @ghybs :)